# question about resulting area from tripled dimensions in a rectangle

Tags: geometry

How do you calculate the area for a rectangle when asked to triple its dimensions?

Here is the question from the test prep I'm taking:
"A photograph has a length of 3 (inches) and a width of x. If tripling each dimension enlarges the photo, find the area of the enlarged photograph."

My understanding is the area and width would be multiplied by 9: 9(3x)

BUT the answer key tells me the answer is 27x^3. I'm confused as to why I'm to be multiplying the variable by itself. That seems like it could yield a much bigger area increase than I'm originally being asked.

Comment: It's a mistake. You are right.

Comment: Let's see if I can get the "correct" answer: we have a $3\times x$ rectangle. The dimensions, when tripled, gives $9\times 3x$ rectangle, with area $27x$. Your answer is correct, and I believe that the answer was probably a typo.

Comment: glad to hear it. thanks for your help!